# Cannot import package "google.golang.org/api/compute/v1"

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I am using cloud function to auto create some VM instance. Before, I was success in my use-case. You can view it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71013896/how-to-create-multi-instance-in-google-cloud-functions-with-golang).Now, I want to update some line in metadata script. But when I save the code, it tell me some package I was import cannot find. Logs is

```
Build failed: src/cloudfunctions/function.go:9:2: cannot find package "google.golang.org/api/compute/v1" in any of:
/usr/local/go/src/google.golang.org/api/compute/v1 (from $GOROOT)
/workspace/src/google.golang.org/api/compute/v1 (from $GOPATH); Error ID: 2f5e35a0
```

But I was view document in https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/api/compute/v1, usage example import like this `import "google.golang.org/api/compute/v1"`, as same as me.
So, who can tell me what is $GOROOT and $GOPATH in cloud function, and how can I import this package.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show your go.mod.

Comment: Here is code in go.mod `module example.com/cloudfunction`

Comment: Not work, new log is `Build failed: go: errors parsing go.mod:
/workspace/serverless_function_source_code/go.mod:1: usage: go 1.23; Error ID: 32633c29`

Comment: If you edited the file by hand, revert back to the original and run the command `go get google.golang.org/api/compute/v1`.  The command will add a correctly formatted require.

Comment: @sonnh try `go get -u -x google.golang.org/api/compute/v1` see get result.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to run 2 command above. I use cloud function in web browser and I don't know how to run that.

Comment: @RobertG, no. That answer not solve my question.

Answer (score 1):

Run

```
go get -u -x google.golang.org/api/compute/v1
```

Then cd/open your directory in terminal then run
go mod init filename.go
then
go mod tidy
Also restart your IDE as that will need to update